# из Dos в WiN

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! как можно путём php перекодировать DOS файл в WiN! помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

только не DOS, а

```
echo iconv("cp866", "cp1251//IGNORE", file_get_contents('путь_к_файлу'));
```

Comment: **кланяется** точняк, 866.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = convert_cyr_string($str,'d','w');
```

Например, так.

Comment: Это по одной строчке да??

Comment: Не=)
$str = file_get_contents('filename.txt'); - вот так будет файл целиком. 
Только следите, чтобы файл не был слишком тяжелым: он должен весь влезть в оперативку.
Если файл очень большой - да, по одной строчке, но в цикле:
$handle = @fopen("filename.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($str = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
        $str = convert_cyr_string($str,'k','w');;
    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Ошибка чтения";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

Comment: спасибо! будем пытаться)

Answer (score 1):

Есть функция [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)

Не помню правда как называется досовская кодировка, но что-то типа этого будет:

```
iconv('DOS', 'cp1251', $string)
```

Comment: Это по одной строчке да??

Comment: Ну для файла будет как-то так:

iconv('DOS', 'cp1251', file_get_contents('путь_к_файлу'));

Comment: Спасибо! а как мне зарабатывать очки уважения??)

Comment: Давать хорошие ответы или задавать интересные вопросы. Вам будут начислять баллы. Кстати, приняв один из предложенных вариантов, нажав на галочку, вы заработаете 2 балла.

Comment: тут все правильны))

Comment: Именно поэтому, это поощряется. Если бы было все просто, баллов за принятие бы не давали. =Ъ